# How to reduce 5 consecutive one to a single one using python list

Tags: python-3.x

Using python, if I want to shrink my 5 consecutive one to a single one, in a list: 
How do I delete the " 4 one and still keep my original index"?

```
for i in list1:
if list1[counter] == 1:
    if list1[index_begin+1:index_begin+5].count(1)=4:
        print("Delete the last four digits")
        del list1[index_begin+1:index_begin+5]
    else:
        print("There is no match")
index_begin+=1
```

Comment: can you give us an example of input vs wanted output of the function

Comment: list1 =[1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0] -> output will be list1 =[1,0,0,0,1,0]

Comment: example2: list1=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] and output is: list1=[1]

Comment: the 2nd example has 25 one and it changes to 5 one after first cycle after 2nd cycle, it became just one single "1"

Comment: ahh ok, I think I understand, your program needs to look for five consecutive 1's and then replace those five with a single 1

Comment: yes that is it. Sorry I was not clear before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did, is use another list in which I appended the values that I wanted from the list1 into, hence the name resultList.

This way I dont have to worry about the length of the original list changing and then making it hard to track the index.

Also by using the while loop, it allowed me to change the current index that we were looking at in the list1, i+=4 allows us to skip the 4 other ones, and continue with the rest of the list.

You can turn this into a function if you would like, allowing you to reuse it and send the list through as many times as you would like.

Hope this makes sense and helps :)

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
resultList = []
i = 0

while i < len(list1):
    if list1[i] == 1:
        if list1[i+1:i+5].count(1) == 4:
            resultList.append(1);
            i += 4
        else:
           resultList.append(list1[i])
    else:
        resultList.append(list1[i])

    i+=1
    print(i)

print(resultList)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this is very helpful.